# $a$ people each throw one $b$-sided die. How many outcomes exist where person 1 rolls higher than everyone else?

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be $a$ people (at least two) playing a game where each person rolls a $b$-sided die. I want to know how many outcomes exist where the first player rolls higher than anything anyone else rolls.

Comment: It’s going to get a bit messy unless $a$ is quite small: you’ll get sums of a power of consecutive integers. You may know formulas for the sums of consecutive integers, squares, and cubes, but for anything beyond that you might want to look at [this](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/sumsofpowers.html).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without needing to solve for it recursively? For instance if a is large I have to solve it for a-1, a-2, a-3, etc?

Comment: No, you can solve it for any $a$ without looking at smaller values of $a$. But you do have to look at each of the $b$ possible rolls for the first player, which is why you get a sum.

Comment: Sorry I indeed meant b, not a (the max threshold for what the other players can roll conditional on first player)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  if the first person rolls a $6$, you need everybody else to roll $1,2,3,4,$ or $5$.  How many ways is that?  Can you generalize this?

Comment: Just something like 5^(x-1)?

Comment: @user2175923: I think that you mean $5^{a-1}$, but yes.

Comment: @user2175923:  you are close, but where did $x$ come from?  The variables of the problem are $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Same thing; I am thinking of the number of people minus the first player

Comment: @user2175923:  now you just need to sum over the various rolls by the first player.  The sum will be expressible by one of [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: @RossMillikan Is there no straightforward way to calculate $B_j$?

Comment: @user2175923: For any given $a$ you can express the number as a polynomial in $b$, but the polynomials get a bit ugly, as you can see from Ross’s link or mine.

Comment: @user2175923:  for any given $a,b$ you can use one of the formulas I cited, but unless you have them, no.  The general expression is $\sum_{i=2}^b (i-1)^{a-1}$.  For $b=6, a=4$ this becomes $\sum_{i=2}^6 (i-1)^{3}=\left(\dfrac{5^2+5}2\right)^2=15^2=225$